# Generate a vector of groups from vector of pairs in C++

Tags: c++, vector, grouping, std-pair

I have a vector of pairs on integers that looks something like this:

```
pair[0] = {1, 2}
pair[1] = {5, 7}
pair[2] = {9, 3}
pair[3] = {4, 6}
pair[4] = {8, 6}
pair[5] = {1, 3}
pair[6] = {9, 6}
```

I need to group together the numbers that come together in any of the pairs.

For example, number 1 is paired with 2 and 3, so they belong in a group together. 3 is also paired with 9, and 9 is paired with 6, and 6 with 4, so they also need to be a part of the first group.

number 5 and 7 do not overlap with any of the other numbers from the first group, so they need to be put into their own group.

The resulting vector would need to be something like:

```
group[0] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9}
group[1] = {5, 7}
```

I want this, and I want this in an efficient way. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to code a relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by direct application of [*Disjoint-set Data Structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Go through the list of pairs, and create a singleton set for each numeric value that you find. Then go through the pairs one more time, executing *union* operation on sets represented by two elements of each pair.

Given the right representation described in the article, this can be accomplished very efficiently in linear time and space.